# Unable to split a string

Tags: java, split, nsxmlparser

I have a string

> Mr praneel PIDIKITI

When I use this regular expression

```
 String[] nameParts = name.split("\\s+");
```

instead of getting three parts I am only getting two, `Mr` and `Praneel PIDIKITI`.

I am unable to split the second string. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I even used `split(" ");`.

The problem is I used `replaceAll("\\<.*?>", " ").trim();` to convert html into this string and then I am using `name.split("\\s+");` to get the name value.

I think it must be something other than space (some special character).

Comment: I can't confirm this. Both approaches work for me. Please provide a complete example.

Comment: This may seem far fetched, but may be the space between Praneel & PIDIKITI is not actually space character 0x20?

Comment: @Maverik: not far-fetched at all -- that pretty much has to be it. @Praneel: loop over the string, print each char as an int, a real space would be 32, anything else is your prblem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work. I suspect your input. There could be a non printable junk character between Praneel and PIDIKITI. For example,

```
    String name = "Mr praneel" + (char)1 +"PIDIKITI";
    String[] nameParts = name.split("\\s+");
    for(String s : nameParts)
        System.out.println(s);
```

Are you sure that there is no junk character between Praneel and PIDIKITI?

Remove non printable characters like this:

```
// remove non printable characters excluding white space characters
  name = name.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}\\s]","");
```

Comment: when i print it on screen it looks like this Mr# Praneel#PIDIKITI

Comment: @Praneel: remove all the non printable junk character like this `name.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]","")`.

Comment: @Praneel: Also No space is found between Praneel and PIDIKITI but only a junk.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing HTML, may I recommend [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)? Its a good HTML parser for java